# Calling a nested anonymous function (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I"m new to Javascript and programming in general and came upon this block of code from a book called *Javascript Enlightenment* (p.88):

```
var parentFunction = function() {
    var foo = 'foo';
    return function() { // anonymous function being returned
        console.log(foo); // logs 'foo'
    }
}
// nestedFunction refers to the nested function returned from parentFunction

var nestedFunction = parentFunction();

nestedFunction(); /* logs foo because the returned function accesses foo
via the scope chain */
```

Why does setting `var nestedFunction = parentFunction();` enable `nestedFunction();` to invoke the nested anonymous function and log "foo" to the console whereas using just `parentFunction();` logs nothing at all?

Comment: And why foo can be accessed even though it should be out of scope is because JS uses somehing called closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're doing:

```
parentFunction()(); // double parenthesis
```

Parenthesis mean that you execute the function, which will return a value. If that value is a `function` you can then execute it.

If you call it only once, well, you just get the function so nothing gets `console.log`ged

Comment: Aha! This makes sense. Thank you for your clear and concise explanation and thanks also to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 5):

Invoking `parentFunction` returns the *anonymous function* without calling it.

`nestedFunction` gets set as the return of `parentFunction`, the *anonymous function*.

Invoking `nestedFunction` hence invokes the *anonymous function*.

The *anonymous function* uses `console.log` so you see `"foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your code is this

```
var parentFunction = function() {
  var foo = "foo";
  return console.log.bind(console);
}

parentFunction()();
// => "foo"
```

Inevitably, you'll want to do something with scope at some point, so you'd do it like this

```
var parentFunction = function() {
  this.foo = "foo";
  this.something = function(){
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
  return this.something.bind(this);
}

parentFunction()();
// => "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function add (x) {
    return function (y) {
        return x + y;
    };
}
var add5 = add(5);
 add5(3);
```

**Explained:**

When the add function is called, it returns a function.
That function closes the context and remembers what the parameter x was at exactly that time (i.e. 5 in the code above)
When the result of calling the add function is assigned to the variable add5, it will always know what x was when it was initially created.
The add5 variable above refers to a function which will always add the value 5 to what is being sent in.
That means when add5 is called with a value of 3, it will add 5 together with 3, and return

Please refer this link...

http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 0):

Because `parentFunction` is returning the nested function, which needs to be invoked in order to run.

```
var a = nestedFunction;
```

doesn't log anything, because it hasn't been executed, until you do this:

```
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite that code as this:

```
var nestedFunction = null;

var parentFunction = function() {
    var foo = 'foo';
    nestedFunction = function() { // anonymous function being returned
        console.log(foo); // logs 'foo'
    }
}

parentFunction(); 
// outputs nothing
// but initializes nestedFunction by its local function

nestedFunction(); /* logs foo because that local function has access to local 'foo' of
the parent function */
```

As you see parent function outputs nothing but initializes nestedFunction variable by function reference. And that function reference can be called as any other function.